# Firefox not completeing stylesheet; works fine in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet

Firefox does not seem to be completing every aspect of the stylesheet for the site (nsfw text) www.theshandy.com

Firefox seems to have implemented the body styling but none of the class or id styles. Every other browser seems to be having no trouble at all.

After doing some research I have tried fixing problems other people have found. The sheet is directly linked (not called by php). The type is definitely text/css. And I believe it has the correct utf-8 character set.

I am really at a loss.

Thank you very much.

EDIT SOLVED:
It was a rogue apostrophe in one of the early ID styles. Apparently chrome and safari will ignore is and firefox won't and it then refused to load the rest of the stylesheet (creating the idea that the body styles were loading but not others.

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Have you tried disabling some of your addons in Firefox? Try using [Adobe's Browser Testing](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) to see if it produces the same results as the ones you are seeing.

Comment: I don't have any addons installed on this copy of firefox. And it is happening on others' FF browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths.. you might be using /css/style.css instead of css/style.css.

This could generate this problem.

Comment: The path is correct and the stylesheet is being fully and successfully implemented by chrome and safari.